# On OpenSearch, mix KNN match and aggregate query

Tags: knn, opensearch

I have an opensearch index which contains documents that look like this:

```
{
   "vector_field":[
      "an OpenAI embedding vector"
   ],
   "text":"the text that was embedded",
   "metadata":{
      "contentId":"many documents share the same contentId"
   }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to query the index, return the top matching documents, and then aggregate them by "metadata.contentId" with the best vector matching document being returned for each "metadata.contentId".

This is the query I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. When I query the index directly without the aggregation I seem to be getting different documents in the top list which higher scores.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {                
                "knn": {
                    "vector_field": {
                        "vector": [...my vector here...],
                        "k": 50
                    }                    
                }                
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "targeting.userId": 250314
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "targeting.groupIds": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "targeting.segmentIds": [
                            537
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "metadata.sourceSubType": [
                        "4"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_refIds": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "metadata.contentId",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_document": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "_score": "desc"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I adjust the query to fix this?